# In Magic the Gathering, what block is the Homelands expansion set?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I can't seem to figure out what block the Homelands expansion set belongs to. Is it Ice Age or something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Homelands was originally released as part of the Ice Age block, at least for tournament purposes. Because it did not fit with the themes or mechanics of Ice Age, it was later replaced with Coldsnap. So at this time, Homelands is not considered part of Ice Age or any other block.

From the [MTG Wiki](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Ice_Age_block):

> The Ice Age block is the first block of sets, consisting of the large expansion Ice Age in June 1995 and two small expansions, Alliances in June 1996 and Coldsnap in July 2006.
>
> *The Homelands expansion, released after Ice Age and before Alliances, was originally considered to be a member of the Ice Age block, although it included none of the mechanics or themes of the block.*

And

> Homelands, released in October 1995, is the seventh Magic expansion. It was the second expansion of Ice Age block until July 2006, when it was replaced by Coldsnap in this role.

Comment: So would Homelands count as a non-block like Fallen Empires, The Dark, Legends, Antiquities, Arabian Nights? Assuming these are considered non-block expansions?

Comment: @rotaercz, How do you define "non-block"? Not having a block? If so, that's already been answered.

Comment: @ikegami, That's what I'm not sure about. I think I saw somewhere that The Dark, Legends, Antiquities, Arabian Nights are non-blocks. So is "non-block" a block? Or the absence of a block?

Comment: "Non-block" is not defined term. If you're going to use that word, you're going to have a to provide a definition. // The Dark, Legends, Antiquities and Arabian Nights are sets. And those sets aren't part of any block (just like the Core sets).

Comment: I saw the "non-block" term used on wikipedia. So I didn't come up with it myself. I wasn't sure if it was a defined term or not.

Comment: @rotaercz Block in MTG means "a collection of sets that are thematically connected" (and also connected for the purposes of rotation). Historically a block contains between 2-4 sets, almost always 3. A set is either in a block or not. Homelands and Core sets are an example of sets that are not in blocks.